# How to impute missing values not at random?

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

My data consists of 202 cases, each stand for a single interview. The variables reflect the interviewers' and interviewees' behaviours during different parts of the interview: p1, g1, pA, gA. in some interviews, certain parts were not carried out. part p1 wasn't carried out in one interview. part g1 wasn't conducted in 46 cases. part pA wasn't conducted with 14 subjects and gA with 27.

Different variables are different facets of the same underlying concept or latent variable. for example, all four variables belonging to part pA - pAx1, pAx2, pAx3, pAx4 - are different measures of the interviewee's cooperativeness during part pA.

I would like to `impute` the missing values while accounting for the fact that there is a pattern for values to be missing, such that if a value is missing for a variable of part pA, e.g., pAx1, then, necessarily that the other values pertaining to part pA - pAx2, pAx3, pAx4 - are also missing.

Help would be much appreciated!

this is my data -

```
df <- structure(list(p1x1 = c(0.54, 0.77, 0.84, 0.84, 0.75, 0.35, 0.67, 
0.23, 0.9, 0.81, 0.76, 0.85, 0.61, 0.8, 0.1, 0.81, 0.96, 0.68, 
0.83, 0.8, 0.89, 0.85, 1, 0.83, 0.52, 0.74, 0.47, 0.51, 1, 0.83, 
0.93, 0, 0.31, 0.95, 0, 0.39, 0.84, 0.62, 0.81, 0.58, 0.7, 0.54, 
0.94, 0.76, 0.76, 0.14, 0.67, 0.65, 1, 0.69, 0.31, 0.43, 0.83, 
0.79, 0.94, 0.84, 0.28, 0.76, 0.78, 0.91, 0.89, 0.63, 0.76, 0.34, 
0.91, 1, 0.72, 0.89, 0.43, 0.85, 0.8, 0.45, 0.12, 0.19, 0.91, 
0.74, 0.88, 0.62, 0.92, 0.72, 0.54, 0.59, 0.74, 0.8, 1, 0.66, 
0.48, 0.7, 0.96, 0.87, 0.65, 0.61, 0.79, 0.8, 0.93, 0.83, 0.88, 
0.76, 0.58, 0.79, 0.65, 0.88, 0.37, 0.74, 0.63, 0.64, 0.58, 0.86, 
0.62, 0.57, 0.09, 0.61, 0.29, 0.9, 0.91, 0.73, 0.92, 0.9, 0.56, 
0.89, 0.89, 0.62, 0.24, 0.65, 0.76, 0.69, 0.42, 0.8, 0.39, 0.58, 
0.72, 0.73, 0.48, NA, 0.5, 0.72, 0.91, 0.58, 0.8, 0, 0.47, 0.5, 
0.85, 0.93, 0.81, 0.89, 0.93, 0.55, 0.78, 0.72, 0.77, 0.44, 0.57, 
0.78, 0.84, 0.83, 0.62, 0.3, 0.67, 0.96, 0.62, 0.73, 0.29, 0.76, 
0.86, 0.7, 0.54, 0.28, 0.74, 0.67, 0.17, 0.05, 0.62, 0.76, 0.73, 
1, 0.7, 0.92, 0.31, 1, 0.33, 0.59, 0.62, 0.78, 0.26, 0.76, 0.7, 
0.81, 0.82, 0.81, 0.83, 0.3, 0.79, 0, 0.72, 0.67, 0.78, 0.11, 
0.32, 0.39, 0.6, 0.7), p1x2 = c(0, 0.08, 0.32, 0.11, 0.12, 0, 
0.17, 0.08, 0.38, 0.12, 0, 0.15, 0.25, 0.05, 0, 0.15, 0.13, 0.08, 
0.08, 0.13, 0.06, 0.46, 0.21, 0.14, 0.19, 0.11, 0.24, 0.08, 0.36, 
0.08, 0.29, 0, 0, 0.14, 0, 0.07, 0.16, 0.04, 0.33, 0.32, 0.22, 
0.08, 0.29, 0.06, 0.43, 0.07, 0.06, 0.16, 0.18, 0.19, 0.08, 0.1, 
0.17, 0.21, 0.06, 0.11, 0.06, 0.24, 0.22, 0.13, 0.21, 0.26, 0.1, 
0, 0.23, 0.44, 0.21, 0.16, 0, 0.15, 0.4, 0.07, 0, 0, 0.31, 0.1, 
0.38, 0.43, 0.16, 0.12, 0.12, 0.18, 0.3, 0.45, 0.33, 0.02, 0.19, 
0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.02, 0.04, 0.21, 0.27, 0.07, 0.14, 0.06, 0.05, 
0.37, 0.05, 0.35, 0.25, 0.21, 0.09, 0.08, 0.08, 0.06, 0.71, 0.04, 
0.05, 0, 0.04, 0.32, 0.4, 0.55, 0.12, 0.08, 0, 0.19, 0.33, 0.11, 
0.06, 0.02, 0.29, 0.12, 0.03, 0.04, 0.33, 0.27, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.19, 
NA, 0.08, 0.32, 0.48, 0.08, 0.07, 0, 0.11, 0.17, 0.2, 0.33, 0.19, 
0.22, 0.33, 0.09, 0.28, 0.28, 0, 0.44, 0.27, 0.17, 0.32, 0.06, 
0.29, 0, 0.1, 0.25, 0.22, 0.45, 0, 0.09, 0.14, 0.33, 0, 0.24, 
0.21, 0.06, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.52, 0.36, 0.4, 0.2, 0.33, 0.14, 0.12, 
0.08, 0.17, 0.31, 0, 0, 0.16, 0.02, 0, 0.45, 0.19, 0, 0, 0.02, 
0, 0.25, 0.43, 0.39, 0, 0.21, 0, 0.02, 0.25), p1x3 = c(0.46, 
0.12, 0.21, 0.47, 0.29, 0.4, 0.33, 0.38, 0.21, 0.12, 0.41, 0.1, 
0.29, 0.45, 0.9, 0.3, 0.22, 0.18, 0, 0.27, 0.17, 0.23, 0, 0.28, 
0.19, 0.16, 0.59, 0.38, 0.07, 0.25, 0.36, 1, 0.75, 0.14, 1, 0.43, 
0.21, 0.42, 0.1, 0.42, 0.39, 0.53, 0.06, 0.35, 0.33, 0.64, 0.28, 
0.29, 0.24, 0.19, 0.69, 0.61, 0.08, 0.37, 0.06, 0.26, 0.56, 0.34, 
0.48, 0.17, 0.25, 0.11, 0.14, 0.24, 0.14, 0.07, 0.28, 0.37, 0.46, 
0.35, 0.6, 0.52, 0.81, 0.39, 0.07, 0.23, 0.08, 0.19, 0.08, 0.44, 
0.73, 0.3, 0.11, 0.15, 0.25, 0.32, 0.24, 0.44, 0.07, 0.13, 0.22, 
0.26, 0.29, 0.2, 0.29, 0.28, 0.06, 0.29, 0.42, 0.05, 0.6, 0.25, 
0.68, 0.26, 0.42, 0.31, 0.36, 0.14, 0.29, 0.03, 0.5, 0.14, 0.54, 
0.3, 0.05, 0.35, 0.38, 0.3, 0.06, 0.11, 0.3, 0.41, 0.44, 0.47, 
0.18, 0.28, 0.67, 0, 0.45, 0.25, 0.28, 0.27, 0.24, NA, 0.42, 
0.24, 0.48, 0.21, 0.2, 1, 0.79, 0.33, 0.1, 0.07, 0.19, 0.28, 
0.13, 0.45, 0.17, 0.17, 0.08, 0.62, 0.2, 0.26, 0.12, 0.17, 0.29, 
0.7, 0.33, 0.04, 0.38, 0.18, 0.71, 0.24, 0.21, 0.41, 0.31, 0.56, 
0, 0.39, 0.83, 0.65, 0.62, 0, 0.32, 0, 0.4, 0.08, 0.43, 0.65, 
0.25, 0.28, 0.31, 0.09, 0.71, 0.08, 0.09, 0.17, 0.09, 0.24, 0.33, 
0.52, 0.21, 1, 0.28, 0, 0.22, 0.89, 0.32, 0.48, 0.53, 0.45), 
p1x4 = c(0, 0.71, 0.78, 0.73, 0.73, 0.75, NA, 0, 0.78, 1, 
0.8, 0.71, 0.88, 0.9, NA, 0.73, 1, 0.57, 0.83, 0.67, 0.67, 
1, 1, 0.47, 0, 0.86, NA, 0.4, 0.88, 0.86, 1, NA, 0.33, 0.73, 
0, 0.28, 0.89, 0.62, 0.45, 0.4, 0.75, 0.42, 0.8, 0.5, 0.67, 
0.33, 0.54, 0.25, 0.9, 0.54, NA, 0.33, 0, 0.67, 0.82, 0.62, 
NA, 0.62, 0.5, NA, 0.81, 0, 0.6, 0, 0.88, 0, 0.45, 0.8, 0, 
0.89, NA, 0.47, NA, 0.3, 0.25, NA, 0, 0, 0.82, 0, 0.5, 0.53, 
0.61, 0.58, 1, 0, 0.23, 0.53, 0.78, 0, 0.33, 0.57, 0.57, 
0.89, 1, 0.6, 0.88, 0.9, 0.5, 0.56, 0.42, 0.75, NA, 0.71, 
0, 0.59, NA, NA, 0.33, 0.4, 0.22, 0.33, 0.3, 0.86, 0.7, 0.78, 
1, 0.92, 0, 0.89, 0.61, 0.6, 0.16, 0.4, 0.55, 0, 0.36, 0.6, 
0, 0.43, 0.5, 0.42, 0.36, NA, 0.33, 0.8, 0.81, 0, 0.62, 0, 
0.56, 0.6, 0, 0.88, 0.67, 0.83, 1, 0.36, 0, 0.4, 0, 0.29, 
0.45, 0.82, 0.67, 0.8, 0.59, 0.17, 0.24, 0, 0, 0.69, 0.25, 
0.56, 0.38, 0.64, NA, 0, 0.64, 0.75, NA, NA, 0.44, 0.65, 
0.67, 1, 0.78, NA, 0.17, 0.9, 0, 0.53, 0.22, 1, 0, 0, 0.53, 
0.56, 1, 0.77, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0.73, 0.33, 0.71, NA, 0, 0, 0.46, 
0.78), p1y1 = c(0.42, 0.27, 0.63, 0.32, 0.46, 0.8, 0.5, 0.31, 
0.59, 0.38, 0.24, 0.55, 0.71, 0.7, 0.8, 0.59, 0.35, 0.08, 
0.33, 0.6, 0.22, 0.46, 0.43, 0.38, 0.33, 0.32, 0.41, 0.24, 
0.43, 0.33, 0.64, 1, 0.44, 0.33, 0.5, 0.25, 0.53, 0.29, 0.33, 
0.89, 0.26, 0.34, 0.59, 0.35, 0.48, 0.43, 0.44, 0.45, 0.53, 
0.46, 0.69, 0.18, 0.54, 0.32, 0.41, 0.58, 0.17, 0.28, 0.26, 
0.35, 0.43, 0.58, 0.33, 0.07, 0.27, 0.59, 0.59, 0.58, 0.14, 
0.54, 1, 0.24, 0.35, 0.24, 0.29, 0.13, 0.88, 0.38, 0.48, 
0.16, 0.35, 0.36, 0.41, 0.45, 1, 0.22, 0.33, 0.22, 0.15, 
0.27, 0.02, 0.35, 0.57, 0.6, 0.5, 0.52, 0.41, 0.57, 0.42, 
0.53, 0.35, 0.31, 0.58, 0.34, 0.37, 0.5, 0.44, 0.71, 0.46, 
0.16, 0.32, 0.39, 0.43, 0.6, 0.86, 0.38, 0.33, 0.55, 0.5, 
0.56, 0.19, 0.38, 0.13, 0.53, 0.65, 0.22, 0.46, 0.4, 0.42, 
0.5, 0.32, 0.42, 0.33, 0, 0.5, 0.56, 0.26, 0.12, 0.47, 0.5, 
0.53, 0, 0.55, 0.4, 0.29, 0.17, 0.33, 0.45, 0.72, 0.33, 0.77, 
0.75, 0.6, 0.25, 0.48, 1, 0.33, 0.5, 0.59, 0.38, 0.22, 0.45, 
0.35, 0.24, 0.57, 0.48, 0.31, 0.36, 0.32, 0.56, 0.46, 0.25, 
0.25, 0.64, 0.91, 0.67, 0.5, 0.92, 0.17, 0.47, 0.83, 0.24, 
0.23, 0.43, 0.32, 0.55, 0.14, 0.09, 0.73, 0.29, 0.39, 0.39, 
0.32, 1.2, 0.39, 0.48, 0.39, 0.33, 0.74, 0.55, 0.29, 0.6), 
g1y2 = c(0.46, 0.79, 0.83, 0.44, NA, 0.84, NA, NA, 1.44, 
0.55, 0.86, 0.35, 0.63, 1.05, NA, 1.45, 0.67, 0.85, 0.45, 
1.13, 0.42, 0.45, 0.6, 1.12, 1, 0.63, NA, NA, 0.68, 1.09, 
1.28, NA, 1.17, 0.93, NA, 0.45, 0.5, 1.06, 0.51, 0.86, 1.09, 
1.28, 0.83, 0.94, 1.1, NA, 0.95, NA, 1.1, 0.94, NA, 0.31, 
1.33, 0.97, 0.57, 0.94, NA, NA, 0.79, NA, 1.02, 0.62, 1.11, 
0.52, 0.97, 0.89, NA, 1, 0.46, 0.85, NA, 0.5, NA, 1.25, 0.75, 
NA, 0.71, 1, 0.6, 0.51, 0.8, 0.86, 1.03, 0.8, 0.79, 0.6, 
NA, 0.87, 0.57, 0.36, 0.64, 0.43, 0.88, 1.14, 0.76, NA, 0.71, 
0.77, 0.7, 0, 0.94, 0.93, NA, 0.47, NA, 0.98, NA, NA, NA, 
0.44, 1, 0.62, 0.7, 0.96, 0.94, 0.74, 0.65, 0.86, 1.5, 0.92, 
NA, 1.11, 0.75, 1.09, 0.79, 0.6, 0.75, 0.71, NA, 0.62, 1.08, 
0.58, 0.62, NA, 0.67, 1.11, 1.11, 0.32, 0.77, NA, 1.5, 0.47, 
NA, 0.93, NA, 0.4, NA, 0.94, 1, 0.72, 0.85, 0.73, 0.79, 0.32, 
0.81, 0.92, 0.93, NA, 1, 0.7, 0.88, 1, NA, 0.85, 1, 0.92, 
0.67, NA, 0.68, 0.64, NA, NA, 0.67, 1, NA, 1.08, 1.21, NA, 
NA, 1, NA, 0.72, 0.5, 0.95, 1, 0.79, 0.65, 0.72, 1.03, 0.86, 
0.84, NA, 1.11, NA, 0.97, NA, 0.85, NA, NA, 1.22, 0.31, 0.81
), g1y3 = c(0.21, 0.05, 0.13, 0, NA, 0.18, NA, NA, 0.12, 
0.1, 0.27, 0.08, 0.11, 0.35, NA, 0.36, 0.33, 0.03, 0.27, 
0.13, 0.17, 0.05, 0.4, 0.06, 0.5, 0.07, NA, NA, 0.08, 0.18, 
0.11, NA, 0.5, 0.13, NA, 0.27, 0.17, 0.06, 0.14, 0.29, 0.18, 
0.05, 0.12, 0.19, 0.05, NA, 0.2, NA, 0.3, 0.28, NA, 0.38, 
0.33, 0.12, 0.05, 0.29, NA, NA, 0.15, NA, 0.07, 0.12, 0.06, 
0, 0.05, 0.09, NA, 0.09, 0, 0.15, NA, 0.12, NA, 0.12, 0.12, 
NA, 0.06, 0.25, 0.08, 0, 0.06, 0.14, 0.09, 0.16, 0.07, 0.07, 
NA, 0.1, 0.11, 0.36, 0.06, 0.29, 0.19, 0.14, 0.05, NA, 0.09, 
0.04, 0.04, 0, 0.1, 0.21, NA, 0.07, NA, 0.14, NA, NA, NA, 
0.08, 0, 0.23, 0.03, 0.15, 0.18, 0.04, 0.15, 0.1, 0.5, 0.08, 
NA, 0.05, 0.5, 0.27, 0.03, 0.1, 0.09, 0.18, NA, 0.1, 0.15, 
0.18, 0.23, NA, 0.1, 0.05, 0.33, 0.05, 0.31, NA, 0.08, 0, 
NA, 0.31, NA, 0.2, NA, 0.18, 0.17, 0.11, 0.15, 0.04, 0.14, 
0.09, 0.06, 0.08, 0.21, NA, 0.12, 0.04, 0.27, 0.14, NA, 0.07, 
0.11, 0.12, 0, NA, 0.04, 0.18, NA, NA, 0.09, 0.17, NA, 0.08, 
0.12, NA, NA, 0.15, NA, 0.13, 0.3, 0.09, 0.12, 0.09, 0.18, 
0.1, 0.16, 0.29, 0.05, NA, 0.17, NA, 0.06, NA, 0.08, NA, 
NA, 0.11, 0.2, 0.19), g1y4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0.17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, 
0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
0, 0.08, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 
0, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0), g1y5 = c(0.21, 
0.11, 0.13, 0.25, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0.12, 0.25, 0, 0.23, 0.37, 
0.05, NA, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.18, 0.13, 0.33, 0.36, 0.1, 0.06, 0, 
0.2, NA, NA, 0.16, 0, 0, NA, 0.17, 0, NA, 0.09, 0.2, 0.06, 
0.3, 0.14, 0, 0, 0.12, 0.25, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0.06, NA, 0.23, 
0, 0, 0.3, 0, NA, NA, 0.06, NA, 0, 0.5, 0.03, 0.07, 0.28, 
0.08, NA, 0.15, 0.15, 0, NA, 0.31, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0.37, 0, 
0.2, 0.34, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.21, 0.37, NA, 0.03, 0.18, 0.18, 
0.24, 0.21, 0, 0, 0.05, NA, 0.13, 0.12, 0.32, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
0.25, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0.28, 0, 0.15, 0.22, 0, 0.12, 0.13, 
0.15, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.24, 0.4, 0.06, 0.18, NA, 0.38, 
0, 0.21, 0, NA, 0.29, 0.02, 0, 0.26, 0, NA, 0, 0.35, NA, 
0, NA, 0.2, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.12, 0, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0, NA, 
0.08, 0.36, 0, 0, NA, 0.07, 0, 0.08, 0, NA, 0.28, 0.11, NA, 
NA, 0.03, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0.06, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.27, 
0.11, 0.17, 0.08, 0, 0.11, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0.15, NA, NA, 
0, 0.4, 0), g1y6 = c(0.68, 0.47, 0.43, 0.44, NA, 0.47, NA, 
NA, 0.44, 0.65, 0.32, 0.77, 0.63, 0.7, NA, 0.45, 0.67, 0.24, 
0.91, 0.47, 0.92, 0.77, 0.8, 0.21, 0.5, 0.6, NA, NA, 0.43, 
0.18, 0.22, NA, 1, 0.13, NA, 0.73, 0.67, 0.31, 0.6, 0.43, 
0.27, 0.26, 0.5, 0.75, 0.08, NA, 0.2, NA, 0.5, 0.44, NA, 
0.85, 0.33, 0.34, 0.54, 0.29, NA, NA, 0.3, NA, 0.13, 0.75, 
0.17, 0.57, 0.44, 0.28, NA, 0.5, 0.46, 0.38, NA, 0.69, NA, 
0.25, 0.62, NA, 0.57, 0.25, 0.52, 0.54, 0.29, 0.14, 0.11, 
0.32, 0.55, 0.53, NA, 0.27, 0.5, 0.91, 0.52, 0.86, 0.44, 
0.14, 0.3, NA, 0.38, 0.31, 0.56, 1, 0.16, 0.29, NA, 0.6, 
NA, 0.14, NA, NA, NA, 0.68, 0.29, 0.77, 0.46, 0.19, 0.47, 
0.35, 0.8, 0.28, 0.5, 0.15, NA, 0.05, 0.5, 0.36, 0.47, 0.7, 
0.31, 0.53, NA, 0.71, 0.31, 0.61, 0.69, NA, 0.62, 0.11, 0.33, 
0.84, 0.43, NA, 0.17, 0.59, NA, 0.52, NA, 1, NA, 0.29, 0.25, 
0.5, 0.31, 0.45, 0.36, 0.82, 0.52, 0.6, 0.25, NA, 0.48, 0.47, 
0.39, 0.23, NA, 0.26, 0.11, 0.33, 0.67, NA, 0.44, 0.46, NA, 
NA, 0.42, 0.17, NA, 0.17, 0.25, NA, NA, 0.23, NA, 0.32, 0.7, 
0.32, 0.12, 0.45, 0.49, 0.45, 0.32, 0.43, 0.37, NA, 0.39, 
NA, 0.11, NA, 0.35, NA, NA, 0.11, 0.8, 0.31), g1y7 = c(0.46, 
0.42, 0.3, 0.44, NA, 0.29, NA, NA, 0.31, 0.55, 0.05, 0.69, 
0.53, 0.35, NA, 0.09, 0.33, 0.21, 0.64, 0.33, 0.75, 0.73, 
0.4, 0.15, 0, 0.53, NA, NA, 0.35, 0, 0.11, NA, 0.5, 0, NA, 
0.45, 0.5, 0.25, 0.47, 0.14, 0.09, 0.21, 0.38, 0.56, 0.02, 
NA, 0, NA, 0.2, 0.17, NA, 0.46, 0, 0.22, 0.49, 0, NA, NA, 
0.15, NA, 0.07, 0.62, 0.11, 0.57, 0.38, 0.19, NA, 0.41, 0.46, 
0.23, NA, 0.56, NA, 0.12, 0.5, NA, 0.51, 0, 0.44, 0.54, 0.22, 
0, 0.03, 0.16, 0.48, 0.47, NA, 0.17, 0.39, 0.55, 0.45, 0.57, 
0.25, 0, 0.24, NA, 0.29, 0.27, 0.52, 1, 0.06, 0.07, NA, 0.53, 
NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0.6, 0.29, 0.54, 0.43, 0.04, 0.29, 0.3, 
0.65, 0.17, 0, 0.08, NA, 0, 0, 0.09, 0.44, 0.6, 0.22, 0.35, 
NA, 0.62, 0.15, 0.42, 0.46, NA, 0.52, 0.06, 0, 0.79, 0.11, 
NA, 0.08, 0.59, NA, 0.21, NA, 0.8, NA, 0.12, 0.08, 0.39, 
0.15, 0.41, 0.21, 0.73, 0.45, 0.52, 0.04, NA, 0.36, 0.43, 
0.12, 0.09, NA, 0.2, 0, 0.21, 0.67, NA, 0.4, 0.29, NA, NA, 
0.33, 0, NA, 0.08, 0.12, NA, NA, 0.08, NA, 0.19, 0.4, 0.23, 
0, 0.36, 0.32, 0.34, 0.16, 0.14, 0.32, NA, 0.22, NA, 0.06, 
NA, 0.27, NA, NA, 0, 0.6, 0.12), pAx1 = c(0.2, 0.56, 0.67, 
NA, 0.7, 0.5, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 0.67, 0.67, 0.57, 0.85, 0.91, 
0.82, 0.65, 1, 0.8, 0.67, 1, 0.67, 0.5, 0.64, 0.45, 0.8, 
0.74, 0.67, 0, 1, 0.42, NA, 0.4, 0.77, 0.62, 1, 0.44, 0.59, 
0.4, 0.5, 0.14, 0.93, 0.82, 0.85, 0.8, 0.71, 0.62, 0.6, 1, 
0.95, 0.4, 0.6, 0.75, 0.36, 1, 0.53, 0.63, 0.67, 0.65, 0.82, 
0.43, 0.5, NA, 0.76, 0.78, 1, 0.88, 0.6, 0.57, 0.77, 0, 0.71, 
0.46, 0.9, 0.89, 0.95, 0.14, 1, 0.4, 0.31, NA, 1, 1, 0.92, 
1, NA, 0.91, 0.94, 1, 0.83, 0.67, 1, 1, 0.62, 0.5, 0.9, 0.76, 
0.61, 0.29, 0.58, 0.67, 0.88, 0.45, 0.86, 0.53, 0.88, 1, 
0.65, NA, 0.12, 0.79, 0.92, 1, 0.83, 0.8, 0.79, 1, 0, NA, 
0.5, 0.47, 0.52, 0.86, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.14, 0.58, 0.7, 0.5, 
0.56, 0.42, 0.3, 0.18, 1, 0.61, 0.25, 0.83, 0.75, 0.78, 0.6, 
1, 0.38, 0, NA, 0.67, 0, 0.53, NA, 0.89, 0, 0.75, 0.67, 0.75, 
1, 0.75, 0.59, 0.67, NA, 0, 0.33, 0.25, 0.8, 0.58, NA, 0.19, 
0.89, 0.67, 0.11, 0.43, 0, 0.09, 1, NA, 0.71, 0.15, 0, 0.81, 
0.4, 0.58, 0.17, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.38, 0.5, 0, 0.72, 1, 0.33, 
0, 0.91, 0, 0.12, 0.04, 0.4, 0.43, 0.34, 0, 1), pAx2 = c(0, 
0, 0.17, NA, 0.05, 0.07, 0, NA, 0.5, NA, 0, 0.08, 0.17, 0, 
0.1, 0, 0.05, 0.06, 1, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0.27, 0, 0.13, 
0.29, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0.23, 0.12, 0, 0, 0.12, 0, 0.1, 
0.29, 0.43, 0.18, 0.4, 0, 0.14, 0, 0, 0.33, 0.5, 0.2, 0, 
0.75, 0.07, 0, 0, 0.11, 0, 0.35, 0.41, 0.29, 0.08, NA, 0.06, 
0.24, 0, 0.24, 0, 0.05, 0.27, 0, 0.07, 0, 0, 0.11, 0.29, 
0.14, 0.25, 0.2, 0.12, NA, 0.33, 0.83, 0.23, 0, NA, 0.05, 
0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.33, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.18, 0.11, 0.14, 0.5, 
0.33, 0.12, 0.03, 0.18, 0.05, 0.08, 0.18, 0.08, NA, 0, 0, 
0.08, 0.67, 0.5, 0.13, 0.04, 0, 1, NA, 0, 0.05, 0, 0.14, 
0.25, 0, 0.12, 0, 0, 0.16, 0, 0, 0, 0.12, 0, 0.14, 0.75, 
0.44, 0.25, 0.06, 0, 0.17, 0.2, 0.08, 0.38, 0.33, NA, 0.17, 
0, 0.24, NA, 0.11, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.38, 0.08, 0.05, 0.12, 
NA, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.12, NA, 0.62, 0.17, 0, 0, 0.04, 1, 
0.45, 1, NA, 0.07, 0.11, 0, 0.06, 0, 0.15, 0.17, 0, 0, 0, 
0.12, 0.04, 0, 0.17, 0, 0, 0.03, 0.14, 0.21, 0.25, 0.04, 
0.02, 0.07, 0.02, 0, 0), pAx3 = c(0.5, 0.38, 0.33, NA, 0.5, 
0.21, 0, NA, 0.25, NA, 0, 0.08, 0.22, 0.29, 0.25, 0.36, 0.45, 
0.19, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.35, 0.45, 0.1, 0.27, 0.09, 0.67, 
0, 0, 0.58, NA, 0.6, 0.31, 0.38, 1, 0.56, 0.24, 0.4, 0.5, 
0.29, 0.07, 0.36, 0.6, 0, 0.21, 0.38, 0.4, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0, 
0, 0.21, 1, 0.42, 0.21, 0.28, 0.29, 0.12, 0.43, 0.58, NA, 
0.06, 0.19, 0, 0.18, 0.4, 0.43, 0.35, 0.5, 0.36, 0.08, 0, 
0.03, 0.11, 0.09, 0, 0.4, 0.59, NA, 0.33, 0.33, 0, 1, NA, 
0.14, 0.1, 0, 0.24, 0.33, 0.2, 0, 0.12, 0.5, 0, 0.29, 0.17, 
0, 0.17, 0, 0, 0.52, 0.23, 0.5, 0.38, 0.18, 0.38, NA, 0.38, 
0.11, 0.31, 0.33, 0.33, 0.07, 0.39, 0, 0, NA, 0.5, 0.68, 
0.43, 0.43, 0.5, 0, 0.25, 1, 0.64, 0, 0.3, 0.25, 0.44, 0.42, 
0.2, 0.39, 0.25, 0.33, 0, 0.17, 0.75, 0.56, 0.4, 0.08, 0.12, 
0.67, NA, 0.5, 1, 0.41, NA, 0.78, 0.5, 0.12, 0.33, 0.5, 0, 
0.33, 0.64, 0.29, NA, 0.62, 0.71, 0.12, 0, 0.46, NA, 0.31, 
0.11, 0, 0.56, 0.57, 1, 0.27, 0, NA, 0.21, 0.22, 1, 0.19, 
0.6, 0.15, 0.28, 1, 1, 0, 0.25, 0.18, 0.62, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.4, 0.18, 0.14, 0.25, 0.28, 0.32, 0.43, 0.5, 0.5, 0.33), 
pAx4 = c(NA, 0.12, NA, NA, 0.69, 0.29, 0.92, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.71, 0.82, 0.4, 0.46, 1, 0.2, 0.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0, 0.38, 0, 0.73, 0.46, NA, NA, NA, 0.2, NA, NA, 0.43, 0.43, 
NA, NA, 0.38, 0.5, NA, NA, 0.71, 0.83, 0.7, NA, 0.75, 0.5, 
NA, 1, 0.86, NA, 0, NA, 0.69, 1, 0.29, 0.6, 0.71, 1, 0.8, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.73, 0.59, NA, 0, NA, 0.6, 0.38, NA, NA, 0.75, 
0.54, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0.19, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0, NA, 0.91, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.88, 0, 0.53, 0.29, NA, 
NA, 0, 0.43, 0, 0.28, 0.6, 0.67, 0.42, NA, NA, NA, 0.91, 
NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0.67, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 
0.07, 0.3, NA, NA, 0, 0.28, 0, 0, NA, 0.67, NA, 0.78, NA, 
0.75, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 1, NA, 0.62, NA, 
NA, NA, 0.67, 0.69, 0, NA, 0, 0.25, 0, NA, 0.5, NA, 0.08, 
0.92, NA, NA, 0.56, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.6, 0, NA, 0.67, 0.33, 
0.32, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.67, 0, NA, 0.57, 1, 0, NA, 0.73, 
NA, 0.12, 0, 0.21, 0, 0, NA, NA), pAy1 = c(0.1, 0.19, 0.5, 
0, 0.2, 0.07, 0.15, 0, 0.75, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.17, 0.71, 0.2, 
0.27, 0.27, 0.1, 2, 0.6, 1, 1, 0, 0.4, 0.18, 0.2, 0.13, 0.4, 
0.33, 1, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.8, 0.35, 0.25, 1, 0.33, 0.35, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.29, 0.57, 0.64, 0.35, 0.8, 0.21, 0.25, 0.8, 0, 0.8, 
0.2, 0.6, 0.75, 0.14, 0, 0.05, 0.37, 0.11, 0.41, 0.35, 0.14, 
0.25, 0, 0.24, 0.37, 0, 0.41, 0, 0.38, 0.65, 0, 0.64, 0.46, 
0.13, 0.23, 0.42, 0.32, 0.5, 0.2, 0.31, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.77, 
1, 0, 0.32, 0.32, 0.5, 0.1, 0.67, 0.4, 0, 0, 0.17, 0.5, 0.59, 
0.17, 0.86, 0.75, 0.67, 0.42, 0.42, 0.41, 0.34, 0.23, 0.09, 
0.27, 0, 0.25, 0.21, 0.23, 0.67, 0.17, 0.4, 0.11, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.37, 0.24, 1.29, 1.25, 1.5, 0.62, 0, 0.36, 0.16, 0.2, 
0.25, 0.22, 0.46, 0.6, 0.37, 0.75, 0.56, 0.75, 0.33, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.6, 0.23, 0.38, 0, 0, 0.67, 1, 0.41, 0, 0.33, 0.5, 
0, 0.67, 0, 0.75, 0.08, 0.5, 0.33, 0, 0.25, 0.24, 0.25, 1.2, 
0.58, 0, 0.5, 0.28, 0, 0.56, 0.26, 0, 0.27, 1, 0, 0.39, 0.15, 
0.67, 0.31, 1, 0.11, 0.17, 1, 0.2, 1, 0.12, 0.11, 0.38, 0.28, 
0.5, 0.33, 0.07, 0.36, 0.38, 0.38, 0.04, 0.15, 0.21, 0.57, 
0.62, 1), gAy2 = c(NA, 0.4, 1.27, 0.25, 1.03, 1, NA, 0.6, 
1.23, 0.69, 0.78, 0.81, 0, 1.07, NA, 1.11, 0.38, 0.59, 0.29, 
NA, 0.33, 0.38, 0.2, NA, 0.5, 0.5, 0.67, 0.67, 1, NA, NA, 
0.64, NA, 0.8, 0.44, 0.31, NA, 0.73, 0.52, 0.84, 1.08, 1.25, 
0.36, 0.36, 1, 0.25, 0.4, 0.82, 1.14, 0.77, 0.76, 0, 0.9, 
1, 0, 0.68, 0.67, 1.08, 1, 1.13, NA, 0.5, 0.73, 0.33, 0.92, 
0.88, NA, 1.26, 1, 0.8, 1.18, 0.29, 0.78, 1.14, 0.62, 0, 
0.62, 0.61, 0.43, 0.27, 0, 1.07, NA, 0.5, 1.25, 0.18, 0.71, 
1, 0.85, 0.1, NA, 0.5, 0.71, 1.18, 0.71, 0.42, 1.4, 1, 0.89, 
0.33, 0.91, 0.32, 0.52, 0.5, 1.04, 0.9, 0.64, 0.2, 1.33, 
NA, 0.67, 0.78, NA, NA, 0.57, 0.88, NA, NA, 0.22, 0.67, 0.55, 
1, 0, 0.81, 1, 0.62, 0.75, 0.67, 0.55, 0.2, NA, NA, 0.5, 
0.6, 0.6, 1.05, 0.89, 0, 1, 0.73, 0.57, 1.33, 0.16, NA, 0.69, 
0, 0.56, 0.14, 1, 0.8, 1.25, 3, 0.81, 0.5, 1.67, NA, 0, 0.8, 
1.25, 0.6, 0.79, NA, 0.52, 1.2, 0.84, 1, 0.46, 0.18, 0.62, 
0.71, 0.4, 0.12, 0.2, 1.25, 1, NA, 0.92, 0.38, 0.58, 1.38, 
1, 0.7, NA, 0.4, 0.69, 0.89, 0.36, 0.67, 0.87, 0.38, 1.08, 
0.94, NA, 0.73, 0.29, 0.83, NA, 1, 0.47, 0.98, 0.11, 2), 
gAy3 = c(NA, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.08, 1, NA, 0.2, 0, 0.15, 0.07, 
0, 1, 0.1, NA, 0.22, 0, 0.18, 0.43, NA, 0.11, 0.15, 0.4, 
NA, 0.75, 0.5, 0.5, 0.22, 1, NA, NA, 0.14, NA, 0.4, 0.33, 
0.62, NA, 0.13, 0, 0.16, 0.17, 0.38, 0.36, 0.27, 0.56, 0.38, 
0.3, 0.06, 0.14, 0, 0.12, 0.11, 0.03, 0.25, 0.5, 0.11, 1, 
0.08, 0, 0.33, NA, 0.04, 0.09, 0.67, 0, 0.38, NA, 0, 0, 0, 
0.09, 0.07, 0.33, 0.14, 0.23, 0, 0, 0.13, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
0, 0.12, 0, 0.14, 1, 0, 0.4, NA, 0.38, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 
1, 0.11, 0.08, 0.05, 0.21, 0.14, 0.09, 0.08, 0.1, 0.18, 0.3, 
0.67, NA, 0, 0.11, NA, NA, 0.07, 0.38, NA, NA, 0.11, 0.33, 
0.27, 0.5, 0, 0.05, 0, 0.12, 0.15, 1, 0.06, 0, NA, NA, 0, 
0.6, 0, 0.05, 0.21, 0.2, 0.5, 0.18, 0.29, 1, 0, NA, 0.08, 
0, 0.22, 0.14, 0, 0.1, 0, 1, 0.05, 0.3, 0, NA, 1, 0.3, 0.12, 
0.1, 0.02, NA, 0.09, 0.2, 0.05, 0.5, 0.06, 0.36, 0.12, 0.06, 
0.13, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.17, NA, 0.15, 0.15, 0.25, 0, 0.2, 0.04, 
NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.33, 0.12, 0, 0.08, NA, 0.13, 0.14, 0.5, 
NA, 1, 0.47, 0.1, 0, 1), gAy4 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0.57, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), gAy5 = c(NA, 0.4, 0.18, 0.33, 
0.08, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0.08, 0.15, 0, 0, 0.13, NA, 0, 0.19, 0, 
0.14, NA, 0.44, 0.31, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0, NA, NA, 0.18, 
NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0.2, 0.1, 0.32, 0.25, 0, 0.21, 0.27, 0, 
0.12, 0, 0.06, 0.14, 0.31, 0.08, 0.22, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.21, 0, 
0.13, 0.09, 0, NA, 0.25, 0.18, 0, 0.08, 0, NA, 0.05, 0, 0.08, 
0, 0.36, 0, 0, 0.31, 0, 0.2, 0.13, 0.57, 0.45, 1, 0, NA, 
0, 0, 0.45, 0.14, 0, 0, 0.1, NA, 0.5, 0.29, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 
0, 0, 0.33, 0.07, 0.21, 0.24, 0.25, 0.15, 0.1, 0, 0.3, 0, 
NA, 0.14, 0.11, NA, NA, 0.21, 0, NA, NA, 0.17, 0, 0.27, 0, 
0.75, 0.05, 0, 0.38, 0.1, 0, 0.36, 0.4, NA, NA, 0.5, 0, 0.6, 
0.05, 0, 0.33, 0, 0.18, 0, 0, 0.72, NA, 0, 0, 0.22, 0.29, 
0.5, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.05, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, NA, 0.35, 
0, 0.05, 0, 0.17, 0.18, 0.56, 0.24, 0.33, 0.5, 0.2, 0, 0, 
NA, 0.08, 0.08, 0.17, 0.12, 0.3, 0.15, NA, 0.4, 0.23, 0.09, 
0.09, 0.29, 0.2, 0.25, 0.08, 0.18, NA, 0.27, 0.29, 0, NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), gAy6 = c(NA, 0.8, 0.27, 0.67, 0.37, 1, NA, 
0.6, 0, 0.31, 0.46, 0.25, 1, 0.53, NA, 0.33, 0.57, 0.45, 
1, NA, 1, 0.85, 1, NA, 0.75, 0.5, 0.83, 0.78, 1, NA, NA, 
0.68, NA, 0.6, 0.78, 0.75, NA, 0.6, 0.52, 0.79, 0.75, 0.38, 
0.93, 0.91, 0.56, 1, 0.8, 0.29, 0.57, 0.62, 0.4, 1, 0.33, 
0.5, 1, 0.54, 1, 0.36, 0.13, 0.4, NA, 0.46, 0.36, 0.67, 0.33, 
0.5, NA, 0.16, 0, 0.4, 0.36, 0.86, 0.78, 0.14, 0.85, 1, 0.4, 
0.52, 0.79, 0.45, 1, 0, NA, 1, 0.12, 0.82, 0.5, 1, 0.23, 
1, NA, 0.88, 0.53, 0, 0.14, 0.75, 0, 1, 0.11, 0.88, 0.25, 
0.74, 0.67, 0.62, 0.38, 0.32, 0.55, 1, 0.67, NA, 0.38, 0.44, 
NA, NA, 0.57, 0.38, NA, NA, 0.94, 0.33, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.52, 
0, 0.62, 0.35, 1, 0.61, 0.8, NA, NA, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.21, 0.37, 
1, 0.5, 0.82, 0.57, 1, 0.88, NA, 0.31, 1, 0.78, 0.86, 1, 
0.4, 1, 1, 0.33, 0.5, 0.5, NA, 1, 0.5, 0.12, 0.6, 0.36, NA, 
0.87, 0.2, 0.16, 1, 0.63, 1, 0.88, 0.29, 0.73, 0.88, 0.8, 
0.5, 0.17, NA, 0.38, 0.69, 0.75, 0.5, 0.8, 0.37, NA, 0.8, 
0.69, 0.14, 0.36, 0.57, 0.73, 0.75, 0.08, 0.35, NA, 0.6, 
0.86, 0.83, NA, 1, 0.73, 0.24, 0.95, 1), gAy7 = c(NA, 0.6, 
0.27, 0.67, 0.29, 0, NA, 0.4, 0, 0.15, 0.39, 0.25, 0, 0.43, 
NA, 0.11, 0.57, 0.27, 0.57, NA, 0.89, 0.69, 0.6, NA, 0, 0, 
0.33, 0.56, 0, NA, NA, 0.55, NA, 0.2, 0.44, 0.12, NA, 0.47, 
0.52, 0.63, 0.58, 0, 0.57, 0.64, 0, 0.62, 0.5, 0.24, 0.43, 
0.62, 0.28, 0.89, 0.3, 0.25, 0.5, 0.43, 0, 0.28, 0.13, 0.07, 
NA, 0.43, 0.27, 0, 0.33, 0.12, NA, 0.16, 0, 0.4, 0.27, 0.79, 
0.44, 0, 0.62, 1, 0.4, 0.39, 0.79, 0.45, 1, 0, NA, 1, 0, 
0.82, 0.36, 0, 0.23, 0.6, NA, 0.5, 0.53, 0, 0.14, 0.5, 0, 
0, 0, 0.79, 0.2, 0.53, 0.52, 0.53, 0.31, 0.22, 0.36, 0.7, 
0, NA, 0.38, 0.33, NA, NA, 0.5, 0, NA, NA, 0.83, 0, 0.73, 
0, 1, 0.48, 0, 0.5, 0.2, 0, 0.55, 0.8, NA, NA, 1, 0.3, 0.8, 
0.16, 0.16, 0.8, 0, 0.64, 0.29, 0, 0.88, NA, 0.23, 1, 0.56, 
0.71, 1, 0.3, 1, 0, 0.29, 0.2, 0.5, NA, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.5, 0.33, 
NA, 0.78, 0, 0.11, 0.5, 0.57, 0.64, 0.75, 0.24, 0.6, 0.88, 
0.7, 0, 0, NA, 0.23, 0.54, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.33, NA, 0.8, 
0.69, 0.14, 0.36, 0.57, 0.4, 0.62, 0.08, 0.27, NA, 0.47, 
0.71, 0.33, NA, 0, 0.27, 0.15, 0.95, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-202L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Without understanding your exact problem very well, have you looked into the [MICE package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/mice.pdf)? The paper detailing the method and package [is here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.169.5745&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Your statement *"if a value is missing for a variable of part pA, e.g., pAx1, that means that the other values pertaining to pA - pAx2, pAx3, pAx4 - are also missing"* ... does that mean that when you have missingness in one variable *and not the others*, you want to discard the others for that subject? (See `df[1:7,1:4]` for the first of multiple examples of this.)

Comment: *"while accounting for the fact that there is a pattern for values to be missing"* suggests that you want to find patterns in missingness itself, and somehow impute values into those gaps in a way that ... preserves that pattern. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks, Rich. I am using MICE. As far as I get it MICE's algorithm drop variables with linear dependency while imputing and I suspect that it does in my situation, and I'm not sure it's the right solution. Actually, that is what I'm asking, if MICE's way to handle my data is the right way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, r2evans. What I meant is that it is not possible for only one of the four variables to have a missing value for a given interview. If a part was not carried one in a given interview (e.g., pA), all variables belonging to that part (i.e., pAx1, ..pAx4) have to be missing. And this is the pattern I was describing. The question is wheather I have to consider that fact and how when imputing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it makes sense to impute the values, then even if you do not have the 4 questions of a part, you can predict them using the relationship between variables and the similarities between observations.
To take into account the colinearities, you can use methods based on low rank, 
see the package missMDA for instance with imputePCA or imputeMFA function, in addition you can have a look at the website

https://rmisstastic.netlify.com/

for information,
Best,
JJ

Comment: Julie, is there a way to retrieve the content of the dimensions estimated using `estim_ncpPCA`, i.e. which variables are involved in each dimension? Thanks